# Please explain the working of the following code

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety

I have the following code but it's output is not what I expected:

```
public class ThreadManager {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Resource sharedResource = new Resource();
        new Thread(new MyThread(sharedResource)).start();
        new Thread(new MyThread(sharedResource)).start();
    }
}

class MyThread implements Runnable{
    Resource rs = null;
    public MyThread(Resource param) {
        this.rs = param;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.rs.add(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println(this.rs.str);
    }
}

class Resource{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    public void add(String text){
        str.append(text);
    }
}
```

output is :

```
Thread-0Thread-1
Thread-0Thread-1
```

but how...

here if thread 0 is executed first then output should be

```
Thread-0
Thread-0Thread-1
```

but here issue is the thread-1 in the first line of output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> here if thread 0 is executed first then output

What makes you think that just because you *start* thread 0 first, it will get to the `add` method call first? And even if one thread *does* get to the `add` call first, that doesn't mean it will reach the *next* statement (`System.out.println`) before the other thread has had a chance to call `add`. It looks like that's the situation here:

- Thread0 calls `add`
- Thread1 calls `add`
- Thread0 calls `System.out.println(this.rs.str)`
- Thread1 calls `System.out.println(this.rs.str)`

(That's a little bit hand-wavy, in that those aren't atomic operations, but it's a possible flow.)

Imagine your two threads are athletes on a running track - the order in which you start them isn't necessarily the same as the order in which they cross the finish line.

Also note that `StringBuilder` isn't designed to be safe for access from multiple threads.

Comment: hey jon, i totally accept your point. but i was saying "if" thread-0 started first, "then" output should be thread-0       thread=0 thread-1. but i am not getting why thread-0 thread-1    thread-0 thread-1 is displayed as output.

Comment: @GauravGupta: Just because thread0 *starts* first still doesn't mean it actually gets as far as the `add` call first. And even if it gets to the `add` call first, that doesn't mean it gets to the `System.out.println` call before the second thread gets to the `add` call. See my edit. Fundamentally, you've got two independent threads of execution, with no synchronization - you shouldn't be expecting any particular ordering between threads.

Comment: @JonSkeet - there is syncro, of a sort, due to the lock on 'System.out.println'.  Because the rest of the thread is trivially simple, this lock dominates their performance.  I admit it's very poor, and not very determinate, synchro, however:)

Comment: @MartinJames: But that's *within* `System.out.println`, which is after everything else of any consequence has been evaluated. So yes, it may prevent the output being corrupted completely, but that's all...

Comment: Thank you guys... yes i got it this is unsafe way to use threads, thank you for clearing doubt..

Answer (score 0):

It's is not as simple a system as it looks. The threads are are swapping around on on the lock inside printLn(),

Comment: Can you flesh out this answer @Martin?  Right now it's not very helpful.  Thanks.